# PHP errors arent enabled even I do enable them in following file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I can't figure out why PHP errors aren't displaye ,
that is the changes I do in php.ini file, but it is useless. When I run phpinfo() function, it doesn't show that any changes were made....In addition I do run service apache2 restart

```
    display_errors = On
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

;   display_startup_errors = On
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

    error_reporting = E_ALL
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

    html_errors = On
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production value: Off
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: are you suer its the right php.ini file, you could have several

Comment: Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  ...That's what phpinfo() shows ...so I suppose it is the right one

Comment: Are errors being suppressed within the actual php script?

Comment: Actually I dont know in which cases they might be suppressed